# Prove that the trajectory of the image of a 3D fixed point by a certain parametric matrix is a smooth curve in $S^2$

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, curves

For $t \in \Bbb R$ we give the matrix

$R(t)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(t) & − \sin(t) &0 \\ \sin(t)& \cos(t) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$

If $p \in \Bbb R^3$ (written as a column vector), then we define
$\gamma_p : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^3 $ by
$\gamma_p(t)=R(t)p$

Prove that if $p \in  S^2$, then $\gamma_p$ is a smooth curve in $S^2$, with
$\gamma(0) = p$.

**My attempt:**

$\gamma_p(0)=R(0)p=Ip=p$. **But is this the same as $\gamma(0)=p$?**

Let $p=(x,y,z) \in S^2$, so $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

Since $\gamma_p(t)=R(t)p=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(t) & − \sin(t) &0 \\ \sin(t)& \cos(t) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &1\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x\cos t -y\sin t \\ x\sin t  +y\cos t \\ z\end{pmatrix}$

is a function of $t$, I guess $p$ is a constant here, so
$\gamma_p$ is obviously smooth since its components are smooth.

**This looks suspiciously easy, given that this is an exercise of a manifolds course. (I don't even have to use that  $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ ?)
Is this correct or is there something I am missing?**

Comment: That homework statement seems to have a little misprint: $\gamma(0)=p$ is surely the same as $\gamma_p(0)=p\,.$ Use the subscript for $\gamma$ always or never. It only indicates where the curve starts. The answer to all your other questions is yes.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks just in case it is useful the following question is to prove that $X$ given by $X(p)=\gamma'_p(0) \in T_pS^2$ is a  vector field over $S^2$.

Comment: These are standard manifolds course exercises. Feel free to post more specific questions if you run into trouble.

Comment: @KurtG. I just found that I can't regard a curve as smooth just by looking at the components, for instance $\psi(t)=(t^2,t^3)$ is not smooth because after getting rid of the parametrization I get $x=y^{2/3}$ which is not differentiable at the origin whereas I believed that it was sufficient to look at the components $t^2$  and $t^3$ and since they are smooth then $\psi(t)$ would be smooth. , ie I believed a vector valued was smooth iff the components where smooth So in my case, I guess there is still something else to be done to prove that $\gamma $ is smooth

Comment: When I say post more *specific* questions I mean a decent new OP from scratch that meets all the MSE guidelines. Do not throw random curves at us without context.  When you create that new post don't forget to tell us how you "get rid" of the parametrization.

Comment: Nobody as said that this matrix is plainly a rotation of angle $t$ around vertical axis ; the trajectory is what is called a "parallel" in geographical terms. Therefore, in terms of vector fiels, one has a global "tempest" all over the globe with wind flowing eastward whatever the point on the sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the exercise is for you to show also that for each $t$, we have $\gamma_p(t)\in S^2$. I’ll let you fiddle around with this trivial bit of algebra (this is where you need that for $p=(x,y,z)\in S^2$, we have $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$).

Given your comments here and in the other post, smoothness here should be interpreted in the sense of parametrized curves.

---

But now, there is one further small a-priori subtlety whose resolution may/may not be the goal of this exercise (the triviality/non-triviality of what I’m about to say depends on how much you’ve already proved in your course). When talking about smoothness of a function, one needs to know the domain, and the target.

- a-priori, $\gamma_p$ is a function $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^3$. Proving smoothness of this function is obvious given that you wrote everything out in components and showed each of them is smooth (yes $p$ is constant).

Let me now assume you’ve also proved that for each $t$, $\gamma_p(t)\in S^2\subset\Bbb{R}^3$.

- At this stage, one might pose another natural question. We know that $S^2$ is a smooth embedded submanifold of $\Bbb{R}^3$. We also know that to talk about smoothness of a map, we simply need both its domain and target to be smooth manifolds. So, one could now wonder if the “target-restricted function” $\sigma_p:\Bbb{R}\to S^2$, $\sigma_p(t)=\gamma_p(t)$ is smooth as a mapping from the manifold $\Bbb{R}$ into the manifold $S^2$. Turns out the answer is yes.

A-priori, these are technically different notions of smoothness, but some basic unwinding of the definitions tells you that smoothness of $\gamma_p$ is equivalent to smoothness of $\sigma_p$ (and the only reason I introduced the two different notations is to highlight that a-priori these are not equivalent ‘by definition’… there’s something (minor) needed to be checked).

The general observation is the following:

> **Theorem.**
>
> Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds, and $S\subset N$ a smooth embedded submanifold. Let $f:M\to N$ be a map such that its image lies in $S$, and let $\phi:M\to S$ be the map so-obtained by restricting the target space of $f$. Then, $f$ is smooth if and only if $\phi$ is smooth.

Comment: I am following Lee's book We've done chapter 1,2,3, 8 (vector fields). Just some bits of chapters 4( Submersion, inmersions ,and Embeddings) 5(submanifolds).

Comment: "Proving smoothness of this function is obvious given that you wrote everything out in components and showed each of them is smooth".... but I thought that for parametrized curves, one could not use that smoothness means that the components are smooth, as seen with the example of the $(t^2,t^3)$ that is not smooth as a PARAMETRIZED curve . So why are you saying is OK to use it now?

Comment: I literally said that as a parametrized curve it is fine to look component wise. I said it is not fine to look componentwise if you’re looking at the image of said curve.

Comment: yeah, but in a manifolds aren't we looking at the image? I imagine the curve living in the sphere $S^2$ and that is the image

Comment: I really suggest you re-read carefully what I said vs did not say (and also what Lee does vs does not say). I am only talking about smoothness of functions here. $\gamma_p$ is a function. $\sigma_p$ is another function. I am addressing the issue of whether or not these functions are smooth. That’s the end of story.

Comment: Anyway, here everything is so simple that even the image is a smooth 0D or 1D embedded submanifold of $S^2$ (and hence of $\Bbb{R}^3$). The image of $\gamma_p$ is a circle of radius $1-z^2$ contained in $S^2$ (i.e it is actually a circle if $z\neq \pm 1$, and it is a single point if $z=\pm 1$).

Comment: I found this https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Supplemental_Modules_(Calculus)/Multivariable_Calculus/2%3A_Topics_in_Vector-Valued_Functions/Smooth_Vector-Valued_Functions, according to this definition of smoothness of a parametrized curve, shouldn't I check that the derivative $\gamma'$ is never 0 ?

Comment: Goes back to what Ive been saying about the multitude of subtly different definitions… which is why I clearly told you which one I am using.

Comment: If you've got a minute, could check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4810129/x-s2-to-ts2-xp-gamma-p0-is-a-smooth-vector-field-on-s2 ?... it's the follow-up from this question