# $X: S^2 \to TS^2$ , $X(p)=\gamma'_p(0)$ is a smooth vector field on $S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

For $t \in \Bbb R$ we give the matrix

$R(t)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(t) & − \sin(t) &0 \\ \sin(t)& \cos(t) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &1\end{pmatrix}$

If $p \in \Bbb R^3$ (written as a column vector), then we define
$\gamma_p : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^3 $ by
$\gamma_p(t)=R(t)p$

**Show that $X: S^2 \to TS^2$ defined by $X(p)=\gamma'_p(0)$ is a smooth vector field on $S^2$.**

**My attempt:**

I have already proven that if $p \in  S^2$, then $\gamma_p$ is a smooth curve in $S^2$, with
$\gamma(0) = p$.

Now to prove  smothness I use the Smoothness Criterion for Vector Fields by Lee

[image: ![enter image description here]

Therefore let $U_i^+:S^2 \cap \{(x^1,x^2,x^3)\in \Bbb R^3: x^i >0\}$ be a chart for $S^2$ with coordinate maps $\phi_i(x^1,x^2,x^3)=(x^1,...,\cap x^i,..,x^3)$, meaning $x^i$ is omitted.

I can just check it for an specific chart since it is analogous for the other ones:

$\phi_1(x^1,x^2,x^3)=(x^2,x^3)$  with $x^1=\sqrt{1-(x^2)^2+(x^3)^2}$
or better

$\phi_1(x,y,z)=(y,z)$  with $x=\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}$

I just have to write to check that the components of the vector field are smooth. For this I use the curve $\gamma$

$\gamma_p(t)=R(t)p=\begin{pmatrix} \cos(t) & − \sin(t) &0 \\ \sin(t)& \cos(t) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &1\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x\cos t -y\sin t \\ x\sin t  +y\cos t \\ z\end{pmatrix}$

$X(p)=\gamma'_p(0)=\begin{pmatrix} -x\sin t -y\cos t \\ x\cos t  -y\sin t \\ 0\end{pmatrix}|_{t=0} = \begin{pmatrix} -y \\ x\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$  which has smooth components, therefore $X$ is smooth

**It doesn't seem like I am really using the chart to conclude that $X$ is smooth in the last computation.
Is this correct? Otherwise, how should it be done or what I am missing for a complete answer?**

Comment: $(x,y)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} -y \\ x\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is smooth indeed on $U_3^+$ and $U_3^-,$ but you must also mention that $(x,z)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2}\\ x\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is smooth on $U_2^+,$ and 3 other similar cases.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yeah, you're right, but besides that how is that I am not using the given chart, I mean the map $\phi_1$ of $(U_1^+,\phi_1)$ or I am mixing two different ways of approaching this problem? Actually the problem said precisely what you just suggested as a note: If you use an atlas, you can work on a chart and say it works also for the other charts. But, that "if you" makes me wonder that is not the only way of approaching the problem

Comment: I described the case corresponding to $U_3^+$ and $U_3^-$. Your "given chart $\phi_1$" (or more correctly $\phi_1^+$) of $U_1^+$ belongs to my "3 other similar cases". On $U_1^+,$ you use $\phi_1^+$ and see that $(y,z)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} -y\\\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2}\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is smooth.

Comment: @AnneBauval I'm sorry I don't see how do you use $\phi_1^+$ to argue that that map is smooth. That map is smooth because the components are smooth. What does $\phi_1^+$ has to do with that?

Comment: I used explicitely that $(\phi_1^+)^{-1}(y,z)=(\sqrt{1-y^2-z^2},y,z),$ and composed it with $X.$